# How to know there are new line in entire sql script?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

example:-

my script is:-

```
Insert into employee(id,ename,description) 
values(1,
   'abc',
   'there is

   new line');
```

if this script run in sql*plus get the error whereas run in SQL developer run successfully.

While running the script in SQL developer how to catch that particular error(SQL developer should through error).

Thank you.

Comment: In sqlplus use `SET SQLBLANKLINES OFF`: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG102

Answer (score -1):

I think you're saying that your code:

```
Insert into employee (id, ename, description) values(1,'abc', 'there is new line');
```

Works only in sql developer, but not in sqlplus?
Your code is correct, I've even tried just in case.

Check if the type for ename and description columns have enough space (You can't put word "Hello" in varchar2(4)). Also, share the code you used to create the table that's troubling you.

Make sure you've put at least a single space between each command.

Also, try this:

```
Insert into employee (id, ename, description) values('1', 'abc', 'there is new line');
```

Comment: I think the OP is saying that SQL*Plus will not allow the CR in the middle of the value for description - you've removed that CR so of course your code works

Comment: @Jovan I think you did not understand what  I trying to say

Comment: Yeah, exactly @ChristianPalmer SQL*plus will not allow the CR in the middle of the value for description(get error msg) but in sqldeveloper, it works finely(but SQL developer should through error message same as sql*plus)